# Forcing LEFT Outer Joins on One-Many JPA Relationship

Tags: jpa, db2

We have a complex table structures Parent table having 4 different child tables, some being one-many and some 1-1.

We are trying use JPA and relationships to Load all. We want to run minimal SQLs to retrieve ALL the data. Preferably in 1 single hop to our Mainframe.

How can I force the Left outer joins on these by using pure jpa relationships.

Even when I try Table 1 to Table 2 ( One-Many ) using One-Many Relationships, Im never able to get the left outer joins. It always runs 2 different SQLs. I've tried FetchMode Join/Select/SubSelect..

Any help on how to force the Left outer Joins?

Comment: What is db name ?

Comment: We are using DB2. There is high latency on each hop and hence cannot afford to have > 1 or 2 hops to get all the data. Thanks,

Comment: are you using Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: Hibernate...I tried CriteriaBuilder too. having same issues